# How get checked value from radio button angular

Tags: angular, angular6

I need to get value from radio button in angular. Suppose to have this html code:

```
 <label class="radio-inline">
   <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" [(ngModel)]="dog" name="gob" value="i" [checked]="true" (change)="onItemChange(item)"/>Dog
 </label>
 <label class="radio-inline"> 
   <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" [(ngModel)]="cat" name="cat" value="p"  (change)="onItemChange(item)"/>Cat
 </label>
```

In my ts page I need to get the value of radio button
like

```
dog.value
```

My purpose is:

1. Set default cheched to first radio button
2. Get the value when I click on radio button

Anyone can help me?

Comment: check out this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52927544/in-angular-how-to-load-the-radio-button-value-when-we-click-on-edit-option

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can bind the data of radio button. Just add the value for radio button and change in the `ngModel`

### html

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="dog" 
[(ngModel)]="dog.value" name="gob" value="i" [checked]="true" 
(change)="onItemChange($event.target.value)"/>
```

### ts

```
onItemChange(value){
   console.log(" Value is : ", value );
}
```

Answer (score 5):

One of the easiest way is do like this:

**html**:

```
<input
type="radio"
id="a"
name="sample"
value="pure"
(change)="onChange($event)"
checked /> 
<label for="a">A</label> 

<input
type="radio"
id="b"
name="sample"
value="b"
(change)="onChange($event)" />
<label for="b">B</label>
```

**ts**:

```
onChange(e) {
   this.type= e.target.value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, in order to group the radio buttons, they should have the same input for `name` attribute.

To solve your problem, you can use `*ngFor` to loop through the radio inputs,

**HTML:**

```
    <div *ngFor="let opt of options; let i=index">
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" [value]="opt.value" [name]="opt.name" [checked]="i == 0"
        (change)="onRadioChange(opt)"/>
      </label>
    </div>
```

**TS:**

```
interface Option {
 name: string;
 value: string;
}

options: Option[] = [
 {
   name: "pet",
   value: "dog"
 },
 {
   name: "pet",
   value: "cat"
 }
]

onRadioChange(opt: Option) {
 console.log(`Value is: ${opt.value}`)
}
```

[Defining a radio group](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio#defining_a_radio_group)