# How can I get value from selected radio button?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

There is my .html code

```
    <ion-list radio-group [(ngModel)]="porsiyon" (ionChange)="porsiyontipigetir()">
        <ion-list-header>
            Porsiyon Seç
        </ion-list-header>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let item of porsiyonlar">
            <ion-label>{{item.porsiyon}}
                <p>{{item.fiyat}} ₺</p>
            </ion-label>
            <ion-radio value="{{item.id}}"></ion-radio>
        </ion-item>
        <button *ngIf="porsiyon != ''" ion-button block (click)="ilerle1()">İlerle</button>

    </ion-list>
```

You see `[(ngModel)] = "porsiyon"` and if I get this value, I have only record id. I want all values from selected radio button.

I mean `{{item.porsiyon}}` , `{{item.fiyat}}` 
how can I use these values in .ts file?

Thanks all of you...

Comment: Use `ionSelect` event for Radio buttons.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 this.porsiyonlar.filter(item => {
  if(item.id === this.porsiyon){
    this.porsiyonadi = item.porsiyon;
  }
});
```

its right answer, thanks all of you

Comment: while this may be the right answer for your situation, this does not reflect the answer to your question. id consider rephrasing your question title.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming what you're looking for is getting the corresponding value for that specific radio button in the .ts component file. If my assumption is correct, this post should help you out.

[How get checked value from radio button angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52927608/how-get-checked-value-from-radio-button-angular)

Basically you'll just trigger a method/function to happen on some event of the radio button. Hope that helps.

.html

```
 <ion-item *ngFor="let item of porsiyonlar">
     <ion-label>{{item.porsiyon}}
          <p>{{item.fiyat}} ₺</p>
     </ion-label>
     <ion-radio value="{{item.id}}" (change)="onItemChange($event)"></ion-radio>
 </ion-item>
```

.ts

```
onItemChange(value){
   console.log(" Value is : ", value );
}
```

Comment: i dont want radio value, i want radio label and p value, i mean item.porsiyon and item.fiyat

Comment: you can pass the item it 's self like this `onItemChange(item)`

Answer (score 0):

you can get the selected item from porsiyonlar array by using the id and find method

```
porsiyontipigetir() {
 const selectedItem = this.porsiyonlar.find(i => i.id === this.porsiyon)
 console.log(selectedItem .porsiyon,selectedItem .fiyat)
}
```

another option is to bind value to the object it selft

```
        <ion-radio [value]="item"></ion-radio>
```

*component*

```
porsiyontipigetir() {
 console.log(this.porsiyon.porsiyon,this.porsiyon.fiyat , this.porsiyon.id)
}
```